# Keyvault after firewall restriction not accessible from Azure Web Service (Web App)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault, terraform-provider-azure

I have a keyvault, where I have stored a certificate, which is required in App Service's custom domain.

This is my app service configuration:

```
resource "azurerm_app_service" "app_service" {
    name = "something"
    identity = {
          type = "SystemAssigned, UserAssigned"
          identity_ids = [data.azurerm_user_identity.user-identity.id] #data block for user identity

    }
}

// This keyvault's data is stored via another method (i.e data/certificate inside keyvault isn't stored via terraform)
data "azurerm_key_vault_certificate" "cert1" {
    name = "Keyvault-Certificate-Name"
    key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.keyvault-name.id
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_certificate" "certificate1" {
   name = "Keyvault-Certificate-Name"
   resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rgrp.name
   location = var.location
   key_vault_secret_id = data.azurerm_key_vault_certificate.cert1.secret_id
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_custom_hostname_binding" "customdomain1" {
  hostname            = "something.com"
  app_service_name    = azurerm_app_service.app_service.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rgrp.name
  thumbprint = azurerm_app_service_certificate.certificate1.thumbprint
}
```

This is my Keyvault Configuration:

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "keyvault-name" {
  name = "keyvault"
  access_policy {
      object_id = "..." // Got by doing az ad sp list --display-name "Microsoft Azure App Service"
      tenant_id = "..."
      certificate_permissions = [
          "Get", "List"
      ]
      network_acls {
         default_action              = "Deny"
         bypass                      = "AzureServices"
         ip_rules                    = local.allowed_ip
     }
}
```

So, this entire configuration was working, till the time I added firewall restrictions which is network_acls block inside keyvault. Prior to that, I had integrated app service with keyvault by adding Microsoft Azure App Service inside access policy which allowed App service to retrieve the certificates from keyvault and bind with custom domain. Now after adding firewall, I was hoping it should work as expected as Azure App Service is a Microsoft Service and I had already added it in access policy and firewall restrictions aren't on AzureServices(bypass Azure App Services). But, the Azure App Service isn't able to pull certificate from keyvault. Do I need to add some another object id as well inside access policy block of keyvault ?

On a side note, when I ran after adding this network_acls, I am getting this error:

> Error: reading Key Vault Certificate:
> keyvault.BaseClient#GetCertificate: Failure responding to request:
> StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an
> error. Status=403 Code="Forbidden" Message="Client address is not
> authorized and caller is not a trusted service.\r\nClient address:
> 0.0.0.0\r\nCaller: appid=<don't-know-which-application-id>;oid=<don't-know-which-object-id>;iss=https://sts.windows.net//\r\nVault:
> vault-name;location=eastus2" InnerError={"code":"ForbiddenByFirewall"}

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that not all services are considered as "Trusted Services", and this is the case for Azure App Services. [This is the full list of trusted services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-portal#trusted-access-based-on-system-assigned-managed-identity)

To be able to reach your Key Vault behind a firewall, you will need to integrate your App Service with a Virutal Network <1>, and on Key Vault you will need to whitelist the subnet associated with the app service.

The vNet Integration feature requires a Standard, Premium, PremiumV2, PremiumV3, or Elastic Premium pricing plan for App Service.

Reference:
<1> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet

Comment: You are linking to the documentation of Azure storage. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/overview-vnet-service-endpoints#trusted-services specially mentions: "Azure App Service: Deploy Azure Web App Certificate through Key Vault" as a supported scenario. However the provided example is with ARM. Might be that terraform does things slightly different and thats the problem.

Comment: @Everton This doesn't work, I had added virtual_network_subnet_ids section in network_acls and it had an array of subnets and one of the subnet is being referenced by App service. As per the azure, App service in itself doesn't reside in a subnet created by us, it's managed by azure itself. So in my case, I have two subnets, one is linked with App service and the other has private endpoint and it's linked with keyvault. And I had tried with whitelisting the subnet linked with app service in network acls as well. Didn't work. Also both these subnets are in same vnet.

Comment: bursson, I linked the documentation of Azure storage but the same applies for any service that allows an exception for MS Trusted Services such as Key Vault, under the network section.

@mozilla_firefox, you're right, App Service doesn't live in a subnet created by us, for this reason, under "Network" you have a section called vNet Integration, which makes all our outbound calls to use the address space of your subnet. Or, you could whitelist the outbound public IPs of the App, which can be found under "Properties".

Comment: @EvertonBarciela, I whitelisted the outbound ip addresses explicitly of my web app(from properties- added all outbound ips in allowed ips in network acls), still didn't work :/ .

Answer (score 0):

Add app service custom domain ip to key vault firewall allowed ip list.